# Oracle Invalid Number in Join Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am getting an Oracle `Invalid Number` error that doesn't make sense to me. I understand [what this error means](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45012348053) but it should not be happening in this case. Sorry for the long question, but please bear with me so I can explain this thoroughly.

I have a table which stores IDs to different sources, and some of the IDs can contain letters. Therefore, the column is a `VARCHAR`.

One of the sources has numeric IDs, and I want to join to that source:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT AGGPROJ_ID -- this column is a VARCHAR
    FROM AGG_MATCHES -- this is the table storing the matches
    WHERE AGGSRC = 'source_a'
) m
JOIN SOURCE_A a ON a.ID = TO_NUMBER(m.AGGPROJ_ID);
```

In most cases this works, but depending on random things such as what columns are in the select clause, if it uses a left join or an inner join, etc., I will start seeing the `Invalid Number` error.

I have verified multiple times that all entries in `AGG_MATCHES` where `AGGSRC = 'source_a'` do not contain non numeric characters in the `AGGPROJ_ID` column:

```sql
-- this returns no results
SELECT AGGPROJ_ID
FROM AGG_MATCHES
WHERE AGGSRC = 'source_a' AND REGEXP_LIKE(AGGPROJ_ID, '[^0-9]');
```

I know that Oracle basically rewrites the query internally for optimization. Going back to the first SQL example, my best guess is that depending on how the entire query is written, in *some cases* Oracle is trying to perform the JOIN *before* the sub query. In other words, it's trying to join the entire `AGG_MATCHES` tables to `SOURCE_A` instead of just the subset returned by the sub query. If so, there would be rows that contain non numeric values in the `AGGPROJ_ID` column.

**Does anyone know for certain if this is what's causing the error? If it is the reason, is there anyway for me to force Oracle to execute the sub query part first so it's only trying to join a subset of the `AGG_MATCHES` table?**

---

A little more background:

This is obviously a simplified example to illustrate the problem. The `AGG_MATCHES` table is used to store "matches" between different sources (i.e. projects). In other words, it's used to say that a project in sourceA is matched to a project in sourceB.

Instead of writing the same SQL over and over, I've created views for the sources we commonly use. The idea is to have a view with two columns, one for SourceA and one for SourceB. For this reason, I don't want to use `TO_CHAR` on the `ID` column of the source table, because devs would have to remember to do this every time they are doing a join, and I'm trying to remove code duplication. Also, since the ID in `SOURCE_A` is a number, I feel that any view storing `SOURCE_A.ID` should go ahead and convert it to a number.

Comment: So what are you supposed to do when you encounter a record with a non-numeric id value?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have validation when records are inserted into `AGG_MATCHES` to ensure that only numeric IDs are provided when `AGGSRC = 'source_a'`

Comment: @OldProgrammer also, there should never be a non numeric id value for `'source_a'`, as `SOURCE_A.ID` is a `NUMBER` column. What makes this tricky is that `SOURCE_B.ID` is a `VARCHAR`. For the record, I inherited this database and would never have used non numeric IDs in the first place if building it from the ground up myself.

Comment: The real question is however, why are you storing a number in varchar column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think I explained this in the question. There are multiple source tables, and some of those source tables have non-numeric IDs, so the matches table has to support non numeric IDs depending on the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that Oracle is executing the statement in a different order than what you wrote, causing conversion errors.

The best ways to fix this problem, in order, are:

1. Change the data model to always store data as the correct type.  Always store numbers as numbers, dates as dates, and strings as strings.  (You already know this and said you can't change your data model, this is a warning for future readers.)
2. Convert numbers to strings with a `TO_CHAR`.
3. If you're on 12.2, convert strings to numbers using the `DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR` syntax, like this:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
       SELECT AGGPROJ_ID -- this column is a VARCHAR
       FROM AGG_MATCHES -- this is the table storing the matches
       WHERE AGGSRC = 'source_a'
   ) m
   JOIN SOURCE_A a ON a.ID = TO_NUMBER(m.AGGPROJ_ID default null on conversion error);
   ```
4. Add a `ROWNUM` to an inline view to prevent optimizer transformations that may re-write statements.  `ROWNUM` is always evaluated at the end and it forces Oracle to run things in a certain order, even if the `ROWNUM` isn't used.  (Officially hints are the way to do this, but getting hints right is too difficult.)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
       SELECT AGGPROJ_ID -- this column is a VARCHAR
       FROM AGG_MATCHES -- this is the table storing the matches
       WHERE AGGSRC = 'source_a'
           --Prevent optimizer transformations for type safety.
           AND ROWNUM >= 1
   ) m
   JOIN SOURCE_A a ON a.ID = TO_NUMBER(m.AGGPROJ_ID);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! #4 fixed the problem, but is not ideal because I would prefer to let the optimizer run the most efficient query possible. Unfortunately, we're on 12.1 so I can't use #3, which I really like (I'm going to press our DBA team to upgrade). We were doing #2 at first, but other devs kept forgetting to include the `TO_CHAR` every time they added a join to the matches view, which kept resulting in bugs popping up, and is the whole reason I'm trying to convert it to a number in the view. At least you have given me a short term solution for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution uses `case`, which has more guarantees on the order of evaluation:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM AGG_MATCHES m JOIN
     SOURCE_A a
     ON a.ID = (CASE WHEN m.AGGSRC = 'source_a' THEN TO_NUMBER(m.AGGPROJ_ID) END);
```

Or, better yet, convert to strings:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM AGG_MATCHES m JOIN
     SOURCE_A a
     ON TO_CHAR(a.ID) = m.AGGPROJ_ID AND
        m.AGGSRC = 'source_a' ;
```

That said, the best advice is to fix the data model.

Possibly the best solution in your case is simply a view or a generate column:

```
create view v_agg_matches_a as 
    select . . .,
           (case when regexp_like(AGGPROJ_ID, '^[0-9]+$')
                 then to_number(AGGPROJ_ID)
            end) as AGGPROJ_ID
    from agg_matches am
    where m.AGGSRC = 'source_a';
```

The `case` may not be necessary if you use a view, but it is safer.

Then use the view in subsequent queries.

Comment: The `CASE` solution is interesting, I had not thought of that. How would that affect performance though? It seems pretty inefficient to perform a check on every row when performing a join. As to using `TO_CHAR`, as stated in a previous comment, we were doing this initially but other devs kept forgetting to include the `TO_CHAR` when joining to the view, and the idea is to remove code duplication. Obviously, the best solution is to refactor and fix the data model, but this is a large database I inherited and it's not practical from a business perspective to refactor it.